# Save DZ.api response in variable

Tags: javascript, angular, deezer

Using the code below I can get a console.log response in the function(response) part, but not in the second console.log. How can I extract that string out of the DZ.api and into child/any variable, when using the dzSearch function?

```
@Injectable()
export class DeezerService{
  child:any;

  constructor(){
    new DZ.init({
      appId  : 'APPID',
      channelUrl : 'https://localhost:4200/src/channel.html'
    });
  }

  dzSearch(){
    console.log('Testing dzSearch() init');
    this.child = DZ.api('/album/12720342/tracks', function(response){
      console.log(response.data[0].title)
      return response.data[0].title;
      });

    console.log(this.child);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using a callback in your `dzSearch` function.

This is my code:

```js
    searchTrack(query, callback) {
        let result = {};
        DZ.api('/search?q=' + query, (response) => {
            result = this.getFormattedTrack(response);
            if (typeof callback === "function") {
                callback(result);
            }
        });
    }
```